# Reserving space in SRAM for SRAM decay experiment (C ; AVR atmega644p ; Atmel Studio 7)

Tags: c, embedded, avr, atmega

I am looking to perform some experiments on an atmega644p looking at evaluating the amount of decay in SRAM between power cycles. My method is to set a number of bytes in SRAM to 0xFF, then when the mcu powers back up, count the number of remaining 1s in these bytes.

For this to work, I need to read and write the array of 1s to/from a known memory address in SRAM. So far I have code which writes the values to a specific address using a pointer set to 0x1000, and then on power up I begin reading the array from this address. However, I need a way of guaranteeing that this section of SRAM memory (say, 0x100 + 64 bytes) is not allocated to other variables/overwritten before it can be read.

I have looked online at the possibility of allocating memory segments - I don't know if this is a good solution in this case, and am not even too sure how to go about doing this. Can anyone suggest a neat way of approaching this?

Please ask any questions for clarification.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `Can anyone suggest a neat way of approaching this?` Specify that region to be unused in your linker script. That's what linker scripts are for.

Comment: Does your SRAM always degrade 1->0? Is this documented somewhere for your particular device? If you're assuming because RAM is always 0 when your code runs that may simply be because that's what the initialization zeros the RAM i.e. to known state.

Comment: My understanding is that the bits in the SRAM have a default state which can be either 1 or 0. The idea is, if sufficient bits are set to 1, roughly 50% will change to a zero as they decay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using AVR/GNU, then when C app starts it clears whole the memory and initializes global variables as required.

To avoid that, you can configure the linker to exclude all start files using options `-nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -nostdlib`

If you're using Atmel Studio you can configure it like this:

[image: Disabling startup code in AVR/GNU linker]

After that you can mark your `main` for it to be called as initialization code:

```
int main(void) __attribute__((naked, section(".init9")));
```

Now you'll have the "naked" code, which does not perform ANY initialization.
That means you need at least to initialize the stack pointer and clear register `r1` (which is assumed by avr-gcc to contain zero):

```
int main(void) {
    asm volatile (
        "clr r1\n" // load zero into r1
        "cli" // clear I flag  
    );
    SPL = (uint8_t)RAMEND;
    SPH = (uint8_t)(RAMEND >> 8);


    ... // here goes your code

    for(;;); // do not leave main()!
}
```

After this you'll have ALL global variables uninitialized. You can declare, for example a global array and check its content on startup.

Comment: Great, thanks very much for your answer. By disabling the start files, will this have any adverse effects if I want the mcu to operate normally and perform other functionality after measuring the SRAM decay. Measuring the SRAM decay is in an attempt to estimate the time passed since the last power down in an embedded device - if the mcu is acting as an IoT device for example, can it still operate normally with this approach? Would it be possible to declare another function, other than main(), to be the initialization code, and then the main function contain the rest of the normal program?

Comment: Also, presumably disabling standard libraries removes functionality such as printf etc?

Comment: @samp99 yes, you can make a workable program with that, just make sure to initialize all variables, also pay attention how the interrupt vectors and PROGMEM fields are compiled, if they are used.

Comment: Also I'm not sure about printf etc (how do yo use them in those MCU anyway?). So, better check the disassembly of compiled code

Comment: I've redirected standard io streams to UART - the point is, with this method my understanding is that we lose access to the standard libraries. Thanks for your help regardless, I need to do some more reading on the applicable start files

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to come up with a custom region in RAM by reserving space for it in your linker file. It is important that it is marked "no init" or similar, or otherwise `.bss`  initialization and similar might happen on it before main() is called. How to do this is linker-specific.

However, writing software for this seems needlessly cumbersome. Simply use an in-circuit debugger:

- Ensure that you are using a debugger which does not power the target.
- Download a program which uses *no* RAM at all into flash. Confirm this by checking the map file.
- Set the whole RAM to 0xFF through the debugger.
- Remove power while keeping the in-circuit debugger connected.
- Wait x time units.
- Power up, hit MCU reset in the debugger, memory dump the whole RAM.

Any half-decent tool chain should be able to do this for you.

Comment: Hi Lundin, The reason it is implemented in software as the purpose of evaluating the SRAM decay is in an experimental attempt to find a solution for determining the time passed in between power cycles, with embedded intermittently-powered devices in mind. Thanks for the tips about the linker; I am struggling a bit to figure out how to do this. There seems to be some options in Atmel Studio for memory settings which I guess adds the required lines to the linker for me. I will continue to read the documentation to figure this out. I am using  AVR GNU btw

Comment: @samp99 That doesn't sound very professional... RAM charges are going to depend wildly on your supply voltage, decoupling or bulk caps and who knows what else. Simply integrate a battery backup RTC in hardware like everyone else.